# Optimization in bitmap creation

Tags: android, service, bitmap, imageview

I'm writing an application that renders a sequence of pictures received in real-time from a remote TCP connection into an `ImageView` element.
The *stream* is composed of single frames encoded in PGM format and sent at 9Hz I tought that a very low frame rate like this should be handled easily using a background `Service` that sends fully decoded bitmap to my `MainActivity`.

Here's my `VideoService` (I'm posting just `run()` method since I think it's the only one of some interest):

```
    public void run() {
        InetAddress serverAddr = null;

        try {
            serverAddr = InetAddress.getByName(VIDEO_SERVER_ADDR);
        } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
            Log.e(getClass().getName(), e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
            return;
        }

        Socket socket = null;
        BufferedReader reader = null;

        do {
            try {
                socket = new Socket(serverAddr, VIDEO_SERVER_PORT);

                reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));

                boolean frameStart = false;

                LinkedList<String> frameList = new LinkedList<>();

                while (keepRunning) {
                    final String message = reader.readLine();

                    if (!frameStart && message.startsWith("F"))
                        frameStart = true;
                    else if (frameStart && message.startsWith("EF")) {
                        frameStart = false;

                        final Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(IR_FRAME_WIDTH, IR_FRAME_HEIGHT, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
                        final Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);

                        final String[] data = frameList.toArray(new String[frameList.size()]);

                        canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, 0, 0, null);

                        //Log.d(this.getClass().getName(), "IR FRAME COLLECTED");

                        if ((data.length - 6) == IR_FRAME_HEIGHT) {
                            float grayScaleRatio = Float.parseFloat(data[2].trim()) / 255.0f;

                            for (int y = 0; y < IR_FRAME_HEIGHT; y++) {
                                final String line = data[y + 3];
                                final String[] points = line.split("\\s+");

                                if (points.length == IR_FRAME_WIDTH) {
                                    for (int x = 0; x < IR_FRAME_WIDTH; x++) {
                                        final float grayLevel = Float.parseFloat(points[x]) / grayScaleRatio;

                                        Paint paint = new Paint();

                                        paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);

                                        final int level = (int)grayLevel;

                                        paint.setColor(Color.rgb(level, level, level));

                                        canvas.drawPoint(x, y, paint);
                                    }
                                } else
                                    Log.d(this.getClass().getName(), "Malformed line");
                            }

                            final Intent messageIntent = new Intent();

                            messageIntent.setAction(VIDEO_BROADCAST_KEY);

                            ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

                            bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);
                            bitmap.recycle();
                            messageIntent.putExtra(VIDEO_MESSAGE_KEY, stream.toByteArray());
                            stream.close();
                            sendBroadcast(messageIntent);
                        } else
                            Log.d(this.getClass().getName(), "Malformed data");

                        frameList.clear();
                    } else if (frameStart)
                        frameList.add(message);
                }

                Thread.sleep(VIDEO_SERVER_RESPAWN);

            } catch (Throwable e) {
                Log.e(getClass().getName(), e.getMessage());
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } while (keepRunning);

        if (socket != null) {
            try {
                socket.close();
            } catch (Throwable e) {
                Log.e(getClass().getName(), e.getMessage());
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
```

The `message` is a line coming from the following text:

```
F
P2
160 120
1226
193 141 158 152 193 186 171 177 186 160 195 182 ... (160 times)
                         .
                         . (120 lines)
                         .
278 248 253 261 257 284 310 304 304 272 227 208 ... (160 times)


EF
```

In MainActivity I handle this trough this code:

```
class VideoReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    final public Queue<Bitmap> imagesQueue = new LinkedList<>();

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        try {
            //Log.d(getClass().getName(), "onReceive() called");

            final byte[] data = intent.getByteArrayExtra(VideoService.VIDEO_MESSAGE_KEY);

            final Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(data,0,data.length);

            imagesQueue.add(bitmap);

            runOnUiThread(updateVideoTask);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

`updateVideoTask` task is defined like this:

```
    updateVideoTask = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            if (videoReceiver == null) return;

            if (!videoReceiver.imagesQueue.isEmpty())
            {
                final Bitmap image = videoReceiver.imagesQueue.poll();

                if (image == null) return;

                videoView.setImageBitmap(image);

                Log.d(this.getClass().getName(), "Images to spool: " + videoReceiver.imagesQueue.size());
            }
        }
    };
```

Unluckly when I run the application I notice a very low frame rate and a very big delay. I cannot argue what's going on. 
The only hints I got from **logcat** are these lines:

```
2019-05-20 16:37:08.817 29566-29580/it.tux.gcs I/art: Background sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 88152(3MB) AllocSpace objects, 3(52KB) LOS objects, 22% free, 7MB/10MB, paused 3.937ms total 111.782ms
2019-05-20 16:37:08.832 29566-29587/it.tux.gcs D/skia: Encode PNG Singlethread :      13003 us, width=160, height=120
```

even with the sum of all this delay (140 ms) the app should sustain a frame rate of more than 5Hz while am getting 0.25Hz or even worse.

After some investigation I found that moving:

```
Paint paint = new Paint();
paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
```

out of the nested loops prevent GC from being invoked so frequently and I found another major source of delay in this line:

```
final String[] points = line.split("\\s+");
```

it burns out 2ms per time so I decided to go for something less smart but faster:

```
final String[] points = line.split(" ");
```

Anyway it's still not enough.. the code between:

```
canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, 0, 0, null);
```

and

```
sendBroadcast(messageIntent);
```

still consume more than 200ms ... how can I do better than this?

I'm pretty sure there's a more efficient way to collect a serie of frames of this size and rate from a TCP server and display them on a `ImageView`.

Of course this can be a matter of software architecture not only optimization of this code itself. I'm open to any new approach besides native code (I'm not familiar with it).

**UPDATE (03/11/2019):**

Activity side:

```java
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements FrameReadyCallBack {
    private Intent videoServiceIntent;
    private VideoService videoService;
    private boolean bound = false;
    private ImageView surfaceView_video = null;
    private String videoPort = "5002";
    private String videoServerAddr = "192.168.10.107";
    private ServiceConnection serviceConnection = null;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        surfaceView_video = findViewById(R.id.surfaceView_video);

        serviceConnection = new ServiceConnection() {
            @Override
            public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName className, IBinder service) {
                VideoService.VideoServiceBinder binder = (VideoService.VideoServiceBinder) service;
                videoService = binder.getService();
                bound = true;
                videoService.registerCallBack(MainActivity.this); // register
            }

            @Override
            public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName arg0) {
                bound = false;
            }
        };

        startVideoService();
    }

    @Override
    public void frameReady(byte[] image_data) {
        //TODO: create image and update surfaceView_video
    }

    public void startVideoService()
    {
        videoServiceIntent = new Intent(this, VideoService.class);

        videoServiceIntent.putExtra(VideoService.LOCAL_PORT_KEY, videoPort);
        videoServiceIntent.putExtra(VideoService.LOCAL_VIDEOSERVER_ADDR_KEY, videoServerAddr);

        startService(videoServiceIntent);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        bindService();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        unbindService();
    }

    private void bindService() {
        bindService(videoServiceIntent, serviceConnection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
    }

    private void unbindService(){
        if (bound) {
            videoService.registerCallBack(null); // unregister
            unbindService(serviceConnection);
            bound = false;
        }
    }
}
```

Service side:

```java
public class VideoService extends Service {
    public static final String LOCAL_PORT_KEY = "video_port";
    public static final String LOCAL_VIDEOSERVER_ADDR_KEY = "video_server_addr";
    private static final int DEFAULT_VIDEO_PORT = 5002;
    private static final int VIDEO_SERVER_RESPAWN = 2000;

    private volatile FrameReadyCallBack frameReadyCallBack = null;
    private VideoReceiver videoReceiver = null;
    private IBinder videoServiceBinder = new VideoServiceBinder();

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return videoServiceBinder ;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onUnbind(Intent intent) {
        videoReceiver.kill();
        return super.onUnbind(intent);
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        final int localVideoPort = intent.getIntExtra(LOCAL_PORT_KEY, DEFAULT_VIDEO_PORT);
        final String videoServerAddr = intent.getStringExtra(LOCAL_VIDEOSERVER_ADDR_KEY);

        videoReceiver = new VideoReceiver(videoServerAddr, localVideoPort);
        videoReceiver.start();

        return Service.START_NOT_STICKY;
    }

    public void registerCallBack(FrameReadyCallBack frameReadyCallBack) {
        this.frameReadyCallBack = frameReadyCallBack;
    }

    public class VideoServiceBinder extends Binder {

        public VideoService getService() {
            return VideoService.this;
        }
    }

    private class VideoReceiver extends Thread {
        private boolean keepRunning = true;
        private int VIDEO_SERVER_PORT;
        private String VIDEO_SERVER_ADDR;
        private int bad_frames;
        private int frames;
        private int link_respawn;
        private FrameDecodingStatus status;

        public VideoReceiver(String addr, int listen_port) {
            VIDEO_SERVER_PORT = listen_port;
            VIDEO_SERVER_ADDR = addr;
        }

        public void run() {
            InetAddress serverAddr;
            link_respawn = 0;

            try {
                serverAddr = InetAddress.getByName(VIDEO_SERVER_ADDR);
            } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
                Log.e(getClass().getName(), e.getMessage());
                e.printStackTrace();
                return;
            }

            Socket socket = null;
            DataInputStream stream;

            do {
                bad_frames = 0;
                frames = 0;
                status = FrameDecodingStatus.Idle;

                try {
                    socket = new Socket(serverAddr, VIDEO_SERVER_PORT);

                    stream = new DataInputStream(new BufferedInputStream(socket.getInputStream()));

                    final byte[] _data = new byte[PACKET_SIZE];
                    final byte[] _image_data = new byte[IMAGE_SIZE];
                    int _data_index = 0;

                    while (keepRunning) {
                        if (stream.read(_data, 0, _data.length) == 0)
                            continue;

                        for (byte _byte : _data) {
                            if (status == FrameDecodingStatus.Idle) {
                               //Wait SoM
                            } else if (status == FrameDecodingStatus.Data) {
                               //Collect data
                            } else {
                                    frameReadyCallBack.frameReady(_image_data);
                                    status = FrameDecodingStatus.Idle;
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    link_respawn++;
                    Thread.sleep(VIDEO_SERVER_RESPAWN);
                    Log.d(getClass().getName(), "Link respawn: " + link_respawn);
                } catch (Throwable e) {
                    Log.e(getClass().getName(), e.getMessage());
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            } while (keepRunning);

            if (socket != null) {
                try {
                    socket.close();
                } catch (Throwable e) {
                    Log.e(getClass().getName(), e.getMessage());
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }

        public void kill() {
            keepRunning = false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: By using a `ByteBuffer` and `native code` (C++ {faster ?})  the storage is not allocated on the *managed heap* (so less *GC* ?), and can *always* be accessed *directly* from *native code*.

Comment: @JonGoodwin my question is more like _there's a different approach to do what I'm doing in a more efficient way?_ I know native code can be faster but I've not experience on it and I think that the lack of performances in this case is a matter of software architecture.

Comment: Well yes I saw your point, but `StackOverflow` is **meant** to benefit **many** users (*not just one*, otherwise it would be a free consulting service) and you did say "*I need to know how to increase performances.*" implying the best that can be done, not for your limited appetite to learn new ways, or limits on how to do it....That is not the  `StackOverflow` way of doing things.

Comment: Uhm I dont' think that I will be the only user to benefit from a different answer. I think and hope that the more generalistic and architecturally elevated solution should be the most commonly accepted answer while a more specific, even if extremely optimized solution should be inherently less accepted. Of course this's my personal opinion. And as I already state, of course it's a limit of mine, I'm not familiar with native code so that answer will not satisfy me and all the people with the same knowledge base

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, you are submitting results with new image changes via `BroadcastReceiver` for some reason. You could improve your overall speed significantly, but removing this logic. And replace communication with a `Service` via [bound features](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/bound-services).

```
    // Bind to LocalService
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, LocalService.class);
    bindService(intent, connection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
```

Then receive connection.

```
/** Defines callbacks for service binding, passed to bindService() */
private ServiceConnection connection = new ServiceConnection() {

    @Override
    public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName className,
            IBinder service) {
        // We've bound to LocalService, cast the IBinder and get LocalService instance
        LocalBinder binder = (LocalBinder) service;
        mService = binder.getService();
        mBound = true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName arg0) {
        mBound = false;
    }
};
```

Then use `Service` binder instance to subscribe `Activity` and use callback to in a `Service` to post new data bytes.

Comment: That's what I meant... I hope ;-) ... now let's see if I'm able to code it... I coded that in this way because nobody teached me something different (until now).

Comment: just to be sure I'm doing it correctly besides creating an binding to the `Service` the message push from service to `Activity` should be coded trough a callback defined into the `Activity` and subscribed by the `Service` itself upon `onBind()` ... right?

Comment: @weirdgyn Right. You need first call something like `subscribeToImages` on `binder` instance (which is your `Service` also. And pas your `Activity` as interface for receiving images.

Comment: besides obvious adapting to my code the proposed solution work and increased the performances of about 150ms. One minor remark, callback invoked from service runs NOT in UI thread hence the update of the picture should be done outside this method (invoking `runOnUIThread()` is not working).

Comment: @weirdgyn it should be done so: `new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).post(new Runnable() {public void run() { yourMethod(); }});`

Comment: but for handler, you create an object in your class holder.

Comment: Just one thing to consider, dont you think allocating and de allocating bitmaps at this rate will introduce faster GC's and in turn your CPU will be busy in GC's causing slowness?

Comment: @SusheelTickoo It will cause slowness, but I'm not sure you will see the difference, if it's only about one bitmap for application. Usually application could stack handling server response in several mb, and processing it in hounders places all over application, with re allocation resources.

Comment: @ GensaGames, very true but here we want to display a sequence of bitmas to UI. And I belive that if we create a Bitmap (as done in the code above) then we have to call bitmap.recycle() at some point of time. Since bitmaps are unmanaged resources we nned to put them up for GC ourselves or alternatively need to have a weakrefrences to bitmaps unlike objects that are managed resources.

Comment: @SusheelTickoo Good point, about `WeakReference`. Just let GC clean it, whenever it could be necessary fo him.  But performance need to test